# I am getting an error in the setConstraints(button,0,0); the child is getting underlined in red

Tags: java

The code

```
    AnchorPane Anchorpane = new AnchorPane();
    BorderPane BorderPane = new BorderPane();
    GridPane gridPane= new GridPane();
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets( 10, 10, 10,10));
    gridPane.setVgap(7);
    gridPane.setHgap(10);

    Button b1 = new Button("1");
    gridPane.setConstraints(b1,0,0);


    primaryStage.show();
```

the child is getting red after inputting the row and column values

Comment: We need more code to help. P.S. I am not an android dev

Comment: GridPane gridPane= new GridPane();
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets( 10, 10, 10,10));
        gridPane.setVgap(7);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);

        Button b1 = new Button("1");
        gridPane.setConstraints(1,0,0);


        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

Comment: I am not an android dev. You should post those details in the question. Try to make a minimal, viable program